# reference other reported works in the form of [-]

Tags: bibliographies

how to reference other  reported works in the form of [-]?

I tried the following trick but didnot work out.

```
\cite{IEEE:Zhu - IEEE:Nguyen}
```

I'm using article document class.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you mean. If you want multiple citations, use `\cite{IEEE:Zhu,IEEE:Nguyen}`. The **cite** package supports grouping of citations.

Comment: Do you want citations to be `[Sparwasser, 1974 - Brandt, 1970]`? this can be achieved with the `natbib` package. You can freely set brackets and separators: `\bibpunct{[}{]}{-}{a}{,}{;}`. [Read this](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) for more info.

Comment: @egreg: , is used for two or more references that there's no specific order among them but - is used for multiple incessant references. I want citations to be [1-4].

Answer (score 4):

Compressing can be achieved with the `natbib` package. Use the option `sort&compress` or `compress` if the bib entries should just be compressed, but not sorted:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

If you use `hyperref`, this will cause problems, but the package `hypernat` can make them work together, but the order is of importance:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypernat}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorting and compression of citations is accomplished also with the **cite** package:

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

that works with the standard BibTeX styles and also with a directly written `thebibliography` environment.